# What kind of Quicken account should I use to track an adjustable complife policy?

Tags: life-insurance, quicken

I have an Adjustable CompLife policy that I want to track in Quicken.  What kind of Quicken account should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could shoehorn this into an investment account.

You make purchases similar to what you would make in a money market account ($1 per share) via your premium payments.

You see appreciation in those shares.

You incur expenses on your "purchases" via cost of insurance and possibly monthly payment fees.