# How should I represent a Whole Life insurance policy in Quicken?

Tags: life-insurance, quicken, whole-life

I have a Whole Life insurance policy (actually [Northwestern's Adjustable Combination Life](http://www.northwesternmutual.com/products-and-services/personal/life-insurance/combination-life-insurance.aspx#Adjustable-CompLife)) and I track my finances through Quicken 2011. What is the best way to set up an account to track payments made to the life insurance policy and its cash value as it grows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of Quicken account should I use to track an adjustable complife policy?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/what-kind-of-quicken-account-should-i-use-to-track-an-adjustable-complife-policy)

Answer (score 1):

Treat it like an investment account.